# Angular 2: Using Set? Browser compatibility & Iterating not possible

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Angular 2 Web Application.
I want to add users to a Game, where I have a Screen with Checkboxes. When one is hit, I am adding it to a Set.

`mySet = new Set();`

`this.mySet.add(e);`

After a User clicks the Button "Add Users", the Users should be sent to the Firebase DB.
I got recommended using the Set by a User here, but then I discovered https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set, that the Set is not really supported by a lot of devices, so I am afraid of using it. What is your opinion about that?
Are there other ways/better Ways to save Data before sending it off to the firebase DB?

Edit:
So it seems to be a legit method (see answers)
Now I have another Problem: I can't iterate over a Set.
As you see, I have a Set, added values.
Then calling

```
    for (let entry of this.mySet) {
      console.log(entry);
  }
```

`this.mySet` is underredline and it tells me "The Type Set is not Array".
As said, I am using angular.
Any Ideas about that?

Comment: why not supported? according to http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Set its supported by almost 90% of browsers, excluding the old ones

Comment: I don't know. If you klick on the link, and scroll down, there is a Table for the Compatibility. So you would say it's good using it?

Comment: yes, posting my comment as an answer, it's perfectly good to use. its an optimized object and a great move towards using ES6

Answer (score 2):

Regarding browser compatibility, you can use this polyfill to ensure that Set will always be available

https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-set

Regarding your question about iterating over the set entries, you can use `forEach` as described in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach).

Below is an example.

```
this.mySet.forEach((entry: string) => {
   console.log(entry);
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! I just updated my Question, maybe you also habe an Answer about that?

Comment: Updated the answer to cater for your second question

Comment: Works fine, very much appreciated :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

according to kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Set which is the place the website caniuse.com check from.
its supported by almost 90% of browsers, excluding the old ones

Set usage and methods http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_maps-sets.html#sec_set